# How to convert the dumped firmware (from linksys-wrt54gl via JTAG port) in an understandable format

Tags: debugging, binary-analysis, firmware, mips, jtag

Issuing some commands for the dumped firmware:

```
$ du -h fw.bin
4.0 M

$ file fw.bin
fw.bin: data

$ file -i fw.bin
fw.bin: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

$ binwalk fw.bin
-

$ enca -L none fw.bin
-
```

The way that I have dumped the firmware is by using the JTAG port:
[image]

And the pins on the linksys router are set according to the figure described in the datasheet (www.cse.buffalo.edu/~bina/amrita/cse524/wrt54gl.pdf):
[image]

And the corresponding pins from the BusPirate v3.6 is put on based on the reference (dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate_I/O_Pin_Descriptions):

The OpenOCD command has been issued such as:

```
sudo openocd -f interface/buspirate.cfg -f board/linksys-wrt54gl.cfg -c "init"
```

The configurations for BusPirate
`interace/buspirate.cfg`:

```
interface buspirate
buspirate_port /dev/ttyUSB0
buspirate_speed normal
reset_config srst_only
```

and the `board/linksys-wrt54gl.cfg`:

```
# Linksys WRT54GL v1.1
#
source [find target/bcm5352e.cfg]
set partition_list {
    CFE         { Bootloader                    0x1c000000 0x00040000 }
    firmware    { "Kernel+rootfs"               0x1c040000 0x003b0000 }
    nvram       { "Config space"                0x1c3f0000 0x00010000 }
}

# External 4MB NOR Flash (Intel TE28F320C3BD90 or similar)
set _FLASHNAME $_CHIPNAME.flash
flash bank $_FLASHNAME cfi 0x1c000000 0x00400000 2 2 $_TARGETNAME
```

and the source, `target/bcm5352e.cfg` , it refers to:

```
set _CHIPNAME bcm5352e
set _CPUID 0x0535217f

jtag newtap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 8 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0x1f -expected-id $_CPUID

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME mips_m4k -endian little -chain-position $_TARGETNAME

gdb_memory_map disable
$_TARGETNAME configure -event gdb-attach {
   reset
   halt
}
```

I open a new terminal and telnet into the socket openocd has opened for communication and I dump the firmware as follows:

```
dump_image fw.bin 0x1c000000 0x00400000
```

The values are adapted from the `linksys-wrt54gl.cfg` file shown previously.

Any Ideas what might be wrong using/connecting the JTAG and dumping the firmware?

Info about the current Linksys-Wrt54gl:

Model: WRT54GL-EU

Firmware Version: v4.30.7, Jun.20, 2006

A copy of the "dumped" firmware can be obtained here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl02cnc5qqddx1x/fw.bin?dl=0

Comment: what if you try `-EB`?

Comment: then its andi instruction that is repeated all the way.

Comment: from the `set partition_list {
    CFE         { Bootloader                    0x1c000000 0x00040000 }
    firmware    { "Kernel+rootfs"               0x1c040000 0x003b0000 }
    nvram       { "Config space"                0x1c3f0000 0x00010000 }` It appears you might be dumping the bootloader instead of the firmware.

Comment: But shouldn't I be able to see this in $binwalk. The dumped data looks garbage. And even though I only dump the "Kernel+rootfs" which is the core of the firmware, it still cannot recognize anything.

Comment: what does `dump_image fw.bin 0x1c040000 0x003b0000` do? if `0x1c040000 0x003b0000` is the offsets for the kernel+rootfs shouldn't you be using those values?

Comment: from man of OpenOCD: Command: dump_image filename _address size_
Dump size bytes of target memory starting at address to the binary file named filename.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right for dumping the kernel+rootfs, i should use the command like that. However, I just wanted to also dump the bootloader. Actually, I should be able to single-step the CPU by first halting the execution, however even though I halt, the program counter doesn't have any operations. When attaching the execution on GDB and using the `x/100i $pc` , i just get 100 `NOP` instructions. I am thinking that I might not have halted in correct segment, but Dont have any idea how to test and resolve.

Comment: ah I goofed. I see now the size of the boot loader and the actual size of the flash are nearly identical save one zero. So back tracking, you should actually have dumped the entire flash memory which should have the boot loader and the kernel+rootfs. Since the firmware is only 4MB could you host it somewhere? I'm going to continue researching what your issue could be in the meantime

Comment: Here is the firmware uploaded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl02cnc5qqddx1x/fw.bin?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61315/discussion-between-brandon-bryant-and-ot0).

Answer (score 2):

The firmware itself most likely is not a binary. Also usually when you run file it will tell you something like: 
`file busybox 
busybox: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1`. My guess is that you haven't actually extracted any binaries yet. My advice would be to use something like binwalk to extract specific files and binaries from the firmware. Running objdump on an entire firmware will probably give you an object dump of every single binary in your firmware and that could be a lot.

Comment: Actually, I have issued binwalk but it couldn't recognize anything. I used enca to detect the encoding, but it couldn't either. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I can offer a few. I would like to gather some more information about your router. If you could post what firmware version you are using, what hardware version your wrt54gl is, and if its not too lengthly, what steps you've taken to dump the firmware. I did go to the linksys page and download the Ver.4.30.18 (build 6) firmware and then I ran a simple binwalk against it and found a few things. I'm thinking maybe what is going on is that you got that flash memory from the device instead of the firmware

Comment: Actually,I am not sure if I have dumped the firmware correctly using the JTAG, but I will make an edit section on the actual post, where I will explain further details.